# Comparison between two images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I need to calculate a comparison between two images in MATLAB that I know have different sizes (for instance `size(A)=100x100 and size(B)=50x50`).

I want to compare with vl_dsift, but dense sift isn't size invariant, so I searched on the internet.  I already know that I have to specify the size of image and here lies my question.

I calculate the descriptors but for what value should I replace "a" in the next line for each image A and B?

```
[f,d]=vl_dsift(I,'size',a)
```

Comment: How do you define "comparison" for images in different sizes? Can you explain what is "vl_dsift"?

Comment: Its a feature and descriptor detector. It extracts points of interest on an image

Answer (score 0):

First calculate keypoint descriptors in both images (`d` in `vl_dsift`). The dimension of `d` will be 128 x number of keypoints (which may be different in both the images). Now find matching between all the descriptors of both the images. Sort the distances. If first (say) 10 elements are smaller than a threshold, then the images are a good match. [Here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hasinoff/320/sift-notes.txt) you can find, how to match two sift descriptors.

The number 10 and the threshold will have to be decided by trial and error.